# how to convert mdx query to dax?

Tags: mdx, dax, tabular

```
IIF(SUM
 (
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(17) :
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,
 [Measures].[Qty]
 ) = 0, 0,
SUM
 (
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(17) :
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,
 [Measures].[Local Num]
 ) /

SUM
 (
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember.Lag(17) :
 [Calendar].[Month].CurrentMember,
 [Measures].[N Qty]
 ) )
```

I am trying to convert that mdx query to dax formula. is there any simple way to write dax formula for that mdx query?

Comment: Did you try using the function `Earlier` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634551.aspx

Comment: @Hello- Do you want this as a calculated column or a measure?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a measure you need, try this:

```
ValueLast17Months:=
CALCULATE
   (
     DIVIDE(SUM([Local Num]),SUM([N Qty])),     
     DATESINPERIOD
         (
          'Calendar'[Month], 
          MAX('Calendar'[Month]), 
          -17, 
          MONTH
         )
   )
```

If it was a calculated column you needed, this can work:

```
ValueLast17Months
= DIVIDE(
  SUMX(
       FILTER
         (
           'Calendar',
           MONTH('Calendar'[Month]) + 17 >= MONTH(EARLIER('Calendar'[Month])) &&
           MONTH('Calendar'[Month]) <= MONTH(EARLIER('Calendar'[Month]))
         )
     ,[Local Num]
    )
   ,
  SUMX(
       FILTER
         (
           'Calendar',
           MONTH('Calendar'[Month]) + 17 >= MONTH(EARLIER('Calendar'[Month])) &&
           MONTH('Calendar'[Month]) <= MONTH(EARLIER('Calendar'[Month]))
         )
     ,[N Qty]
    )
)
```